# Update-Database does not apply migration to database

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

For packages in model project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0">
```

with

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

with sdk installed on machine:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.604 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I run command as follow:

```
PM> Update-Database -Context DalContext -Verbose
Using project 'DAL\Geotik.DAL.DbAL'.
Using startup project 'WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\HubertWojtowiczGeoti\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi.runtimeconfig.json "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.2.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" database update --context DalContext --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Geotik.DAL.DbAL.dll --startup-assembly D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi.dll --project-dir D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\DAL\Geotik.DAL.DbAL\ --language C# --working-dir D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik --root-namespace Geotik.DAL.DbAL
Using assembly 'Geotik.DAL.DbAL'.
Using startup assembly 'Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi'.
Using application base 'D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2'.
Using working directory 'D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\WebApis\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi\Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi'.
Using root namespace 'Geotik.DAL.DbAL'.
Using project directory 'D:\Repos\Geotik\Geotik\DAL\Geotik.DAL.DbAL\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding IWebHost accessor...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from IWebHost accessor on 'Program'.
Found DbContext 'DalContext'.
Found DbContext 'TdcDalContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'DalContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Geotik.WebApis.GeotikApi'...
No design-time services were found.
Done.
```

It does nothing on database. I expected it will add migration but it didn't.
I had before:
[image]

In VS2019 I have migrations:

[image]

I did additional checks:

1. When I created empty database and run the same command it created only empty `__EFMigrationsHistory` table there.
2. I reinstalled all nuget packages, but it does not help.

Can sb please help me figure out why it does not apply last migration `20200227120415_ChangeMergeStatusIdCollumnInFuelingMergeTable`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's not finding your migration classes.

> Found DbContext 'DalContext'.
>   Found DbContext 'TdcDalContext'.
>   Using context 'DalContext'.

Are your migrations annotated with `[DbContext(typeof(TdcDalContext))]` instead of DalContext?

Comment: Using context 'DalContext' is what I expected. I have no migration in solution for 'TdcDalContext'. Anottating 'DalContext' migrations with ` [DbContext(typeof(TdcDalContext))]` attribute does not afffect anything when I run update-database. I tried to indicate migration project explocitely by command `Update-Database -Project Geotik.DAL.DbAL -Context DalContext -Verbose` but I got the same result as before.

Comment: What is interesting my collegue performed test on the same repo state using the same commands and he was able to update database with success. It looks like not problem in code or in running update command.

Comment: Before your suggestion we did not have this attribute added over migrations by default `IMigrationsCodeGenerator`.
I our project `TdcDalContext` is read-only thats why we do not have migrations for it.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared, that my collegue added code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultItemExcludes Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">Migrations\**\*.Designer.cs</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to optimize build time in CICD. 
This caused migrations were not discoverable for ef tools.